# How to convert a 1x3x10 double to a 10x3 matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am new to Matlab. I came across a problem today. I am not sure how to solve them.
1. How can I convert a 1x3x10 double to a 10x3 matrix.
when I clicked on the double file it gives me the results like,

```
val(:,:,1) =

-50.3649  -48.9813  -45.3811

val(:,:,2) =

-50.1935  -48.7253  -45.7192

val(:,:,3) =

-50.5978  -48.6429  -45.6528
.
.
.
val(:,:,10)=

-46.4783  -52.7739  -49.3828
```

In this case I want all the values in a form of 10x3 matrix (ie 10 rows and 3 columns)

2. Is there a direct way to convert a 1x10 struct to a 10x3 matrix? If yes then how can we convert it? I tried to find the results online but I failed.
   The struct gives me results like

   [-50.3648951714758,-48.9813202590474,-45.3810932536002]
   [-50.1935035205826,-48.7252709173320,-45.7192148933862]
   [-50.5977714391947,-48.6428804170690,-45.6528299629331]
   .
   .
   Apologies if its a silly question to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html?refresh=true) the dimensions of your array like so:

```
val = permute(val,[3 2 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function too gives the same answer.

```
val = reshape(val,[],3)
```